# Hooking new/delete C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to hook on new/delete in C++
When it comes to malloc/free it is simple: just read it:
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Hooks-for-Malloc.html

But, what about allocation in C++ with new/delete?

P.S. I mean G++/GCC

Comment: You can add overloads for `operator new` and `operator delete`. Not that doing so is a very good idea.

Comment: Why is this question voted down that often? A lot of people are not aware one can overload new/delete.

Answer (score 4):

It is just as simple, just overload the new/new[]/delete/delete[] functions:

```
void* operator new(size_t size)
void* operator new[](size_t size)
void  operator delete(void* ptr)
void  operator delete[](void* ptr)
```

See [Overloading Global operator new and delete](https://web.archive.org/web/20201123190342/https://oroboro.com/overloading-operator-new/)
Also see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/) for more information about the default new/delete functions

Comment: I don't know if I will get any answer after 4 years, but I try. Does this answer mean that the new/delete overloading has not to be done for all the classes but only once (globally)? And after this is done is it possible to use the non-overloaded new? The purpose is tracing allocations to prevent memory leaks in a system in which Valgrind-like tools cannot be used. tools

Comment: @Cubo78 The overloading cannot be done globally, but I believe you could put it in one class with any classes you need inheriting from it.

Answer (score 1):

Just globally overload the new and delete operator. Simple example i have written below.

```
void * operator new(size_t size){
    int *p=(int*)malloc(size);
    cout<<*p<<" "<<p<<endl;
    return p;
}
void operator delete(void *p)
{   free(p);
}
void * operator new[](size_t size){
    void *p=malloc(size);
    return p;
}
void operator delete[](void *p){
     free(p);
}
```